# MongoDb convert field type from array to NumberLong

Tags: arrays, mongodb, integer

I have a collection of documents with a array field:

expedition_ids : [4]

Since there is only on item in the array, I wish to convert it to:

expedition_id : 4

I already have worked on the renaming. I just need the query to convert the array, taking the 0 key value of the array, and changing it to a number. I've tried various queries for changing type I found on the net but can't seem to come up with the answer. Any help please?

Edit: I imagine it's something like this, but need the right value for x.expedition_ids

```
db.transcriptions.find({expedition_ids: {$exists:true}}).forEach( function(x) {
   db.transcriptions.update({_id: x._id}, {$set: {expedition_ids: x.expedition_ids}});
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is work for me:

```
{
    "_id": NumberLong(12345678),
    "name": "testDocument",
    "relations": [ 
        {
            "mainIds" : [ 
                NumberLong(8095698)
            ],
            "relationType" : "parent"
        }
    ]
}

db.Test.find({$and:[{"relations": {$exists: true}}, {"relations.mainIds": {$exists: true}}, {"relations.mainIds":{$type: 4}}]}).forEach( function (x) { x.relations.forEach( function (s) {s.mainIds = NumberLong(s.mainIds[0]); db.Test.save(x); }) });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is an easier way, but this ended up working for me.

```
db.transcriptions.find({expedition_ids: {$exists:true}}).forEach( function(x) {
    var arr = x.expedition_ids;
    var value = arr[0];
    db.transcriptions.update({_id: x._id}, {$set: {expedition_ids: value}});
});
```